# Grafos en Latex

Tags: latex

¿Alguien sabe como hacer este grafico en latex?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma oficial es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas toooooooooooooda la pregunta (incluyendo el título!) 
para que otros te respondan y para que no termine cerrada. 
Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta todas las veces que quieras.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias!! Hago el recorrido para estar más al tanto!!

Comment: A la próxima, alguito de código pa ver dónde quieres poner el grafo, caería bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tikz es una poderosa librería gráfica con la que puedes dibujar cualquier cosa.

En tu caso podría ser útil utilizar una matriz para posicionar los elementos principales (el texto "regla", los asteriscos) y después usar el comando `\draw` para dibujar las flechas con las anotaciones. Así:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,]
  \matrix [column sep=2cm, nodes={anchor=west, inner sep=1em}]
  {
    \node{regla};  \\
    \node(a) {$*$};  \\
    \node(b) {$*$};  & \node(c) {$*$}; \\
  };
  \draw[->] (a.east) -- (c) node[above, midway] {$u$};
  \draw[->] (b) -- (c) node[below, midway] {$1-u$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Answer (score 0):

No sé si la librería [TikZ](https://texample.net//tikz/examples/tag/graphs/) sea lo que necesitas.

Un ejemplo :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n6) at (1,10) {6};
  \node (n4) at (4,8)  {4};
  \node (n5) at (8,9)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (11,8) {1};
  \node (n2) at (9,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (5,5)  {3};

  \foreach \from/\to in {n6/n4,n4/n5,n5/n1,n1/n2,n2/n5,n2/n3,n3/n4}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Que daría algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]